# Equivalent of CTRL + C (break) in android console

Tags: keyboard, terminal

Recently I discovered, that via QPython console I can execute android (linux) commands. Ping works. Question is: how to interrupt it's output on smartphone? CTRL + C obviously isn't the answer.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

<kbd>Vol Down</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> is functionally equivalent to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

There may be a way to send the modifier keys through the terminal app, however I have never used that app so I can't say. On Terminal Emulator you can long press the screen and send the control key from the pop up menu.

Also you could install [Hackers Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard) which includes a full desktop keyboard including control and alt keys.

Answer (score 0):

Most Term Emus use <kbd>Vol Dn</kbd> as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and use <kbd>Vol Up</kbd> as <kbd>Fn</kbd>. So in your case simply hold the Volume Down key and then press C on your keyboard (essestially, any IME works).

Comment: fn - isn't the fn key a modifier key found mainly on laptops that's used to access additional functions on keys like the function keys?

Comment: @BradHein Basically **Fn** is used to modify keys, *any keys!!!*